# Why widget does not work after reboot?

Tags: android, widget, reboot

I have this simple widget and when I click on it, it should open my activity, it works, but it doesn't work after reboot. I must delete and then again add widget to my homescreen, because when I click on widget widget doesn't respond and doesn't open my activity. So where is the problem?

**Code:**

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            context.startService(new Intent(context, WidgetService.class));

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetDialog.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout_widget, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context){
        context.startService(new Intent(context, WidgetService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context){
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, WidgetService.class));
    }
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, I did. Anyway, thank you for asking.

Comment: You should post your solution instead of saying "thank you for asking".

Comment: @Adam could you explain how you solved the problem please? The same way as strange answers suggests?

Comment: I have this issue on some old Android version and I remember that sometimes methods OnUpdate and OnEnabled were not called after reboot, but I think that it should work without any issue nowadays.

Comment: I would like to help you guys, but it was so long ago, that I really don't remember how I solved it.

Answer (score 8):

After reboot you OnEnabled is called instead of onUpdate so move the code from onUpdate into a separate method and then call that method to update all widgets from onEnabled

Comment: Note that for me (on Pixel 3) it can take 15+ seconds for `onEnabled()` to be called after signing in after a reboot, so be patient!

Answer (score 1):

The AppWidgetProvider which widgets inherit calls `onUpdate` on startup when it receives `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` from the operating system.

If you override `onReceive` without calling `super.onReceive()`, you would need to intercept this Intent on your own.